# design pattern vuex electron

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, vuex

What's the current state of the art in relation to using vuex with electron - particularly in relation to sharing store, mutation, actions across both main and renderer proceeses.

I see legacy information available in relation to vuex-electron and the createPersistedState, createSharedMutations plugins, but this does not appear to be functional with contemporary versions of the platform.

Is there a way or is it best practise to continue using ipc and keep all vuex operations in the renderer?